# Upload User images to timeline in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

We have got requirement to share on facebook in particular format.

It should look like this Sample image post

[image]

Now I'm not sure which facebook api should we use to get this format post.

I have tried these api's:

- facebook story, but it gives only one image and post is something like "XXX liked cool photo"
- /me/photo (upload photo). Only one photo at a time. Batch request creates multiple post
- /me/feed - multiple photo cant share once

Any other api's ? Any suggestion on this whether this format is possible or not?

**IF NOT**

- How we can upload multiple photos which looks like single post?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not possible

Comment: Any api to upload multiple photos appears as single post?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook determines how multiple images on the timeline are displayed. You would need to upload multiple images using the API and hope Facebook group them together. You are more likely to get this type of feed if you create an album for the photos.